# 404 status code found when I deployed application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I am getting a 404 status code after deploying the application on IIS Windows Server 2012 even if the URL path is perfect and files exist.

Actually, what I did is we have 2 different servers and both servers are running on the same public IP address.

I tried deploying an application with an SSL certificate on server 1 with the Domain name abc.com and it works perfectly for me.

But, when I tried to deploy the same application on server 2 with the same SSL certificate with the same domain name abc.com, it gave me a 404 status code error (File or directory not found).

However, I removed the application from server 1 to test on server 2.

Also, I tried to generate and use a new SSL certificate (for the same domain name abc.com) for Server 2, but, it still gives me the same error.

I'm getting the same error even if I tried to change the domain name (with xyz.com) and used its SSL certificate on server 2.

I tried searching for various solutions for it on Google and also tried to apply it but no one works for me.

Moreover, I tried to deploy a simple HTML page application (Hello World message) on IIS for testing on Server 2 without SSL certificate but I still get the same error.

It would be nice if someone could help me with this, please.

Comment: @Austin I have used the static IP of the ISP and updated DNS records with type A on the GoDaddy site. Do I need to set up anything on my server 2?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and it is pinging with the correct IP address and it is a public IP address. Also, this is our self-hosted server. Thanks.

Comment: `both servers are running on the same static IP.` I cannot understand why these servers use same IP. Usually, DNS maps the domain to a specific IP address so that request can forward to a server. If two servers use same IP, which server should receive the request? Another thing is what the 404 error page is? Does it show like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V38JM.png

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error message you said. I was actually talking about public IP addresses for both servers (assigned by an internet service provider).
So, what should I do? Do I need to provide the IP address of the server with the public IP address? Thanks

Comment: If you get this error page, that means server2 received requests, all your setting are correctly. Please check which site on server2 bind the hosts name of abc.com. Then check if the site enable default document and if thers's any file in site root folder.

Comment: @BruceZhang I have tried to create a very simple application with an HTML page and try to bind the hostname abc.com with HTTP and the port number I have chosen is 80.
Also, I set the default document at the top of the list with the index.html page which is available in the folder. I don't know why it doesn't show up even though it's not a secure site (I did not use it with the SSL certificate for testing). I don't know what am I missing?

Comment: I think you can try another method. Disable default document, enable directory browsing. Then access the domain to check if it shows all files in site root folder. If  it shows files, click the index.html to check if it will load.

Comment: @BruceZhang I tried to disable the default document and enable directory browsing but it does not show me a list of files in the browser.
It shows me the IIS 8 default page. I have attached a screenshot of it. Thanks 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxSZi.png

Comment: Can you show the binding information of this site?

Comment: Here, I have attached an image of binding information for the site. I'm sorry but I can't show you the exact domain name right now but it looks just like the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wFfg.png